# Heater blower works, ac blower and compressor won’t shut off

Tags: hvac

I have a mobile home unit, Coleman Evcon model DGRT070AUA. The unit controls blower and heat/ac internally, so thermostat is only on/off control. The heater side works fine, but the ac side won’t shut off the blower or the compressor. I changed the ac compressor coil first as it was stuck on, but it didn’t fix the problem. Any ideas?

Comment: The ac compressor coil is an electrical component that uses 24v dc to pull the 120v ac coil in to complete the circuit and send power to the compressor.

Comment: Actually, it’s called a contractor coil. We have a ton of them at work, to save time, we will say to check so and so coil. Heater coil, charging coil. Sorry, I was talking like I would to the other maintenance guys. As I don’t have schematics to the unit, I’m not sure where the air conditioning is getting it’s 24v signal that pulls the contactor coil in.